# Gradient Descent code used to minimize a convex function not finding minima

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numerical-methods, gradient-descent

I am trying to find the geometric median for a set of of n points. For this I have to minimize the sum of sqrt((x-xn)^2+(y-yn)^2).

To do this I decided to try a method of Gradient Descents. The gradient of this function was just the sum of (x-xn)/sqrt((x-xn)^2+(y-yn)^2) for x, and a similar one for y. However, no matter how small the step size, or how many iterations, my code seems to coverage to points way off target.

Here is the offending code segment

```
def geoMean(points, gamma, iters):
#Take the initial guess to be the centroid
    guess = centerOfMass(points)

    for rep in range(0, iters):
        gradient = [0, 0]

        for point in points:
        #Sum up the partials for every point
            gradient[0] += (guess[0]-point[0])/(math.sqrt((guess[0]-point[0])**2+(guess[1]-point[1])**2))
            gradient[1] += (guess[1]-point[1])/(math.sqrt((guess[0]-point[0])**2+(guess[1]-point[1])**2))
    #Refine the guess  
        guess = (guess[0]-gamma*gradient[0], guess[1]-gamma*gradient[1])

    return guess
```

Important note: The points could be anywhere, they are not strictly in the first quadrant.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "geometric mean for a set of n points"? I know what the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of a collection of positive (real) numbers is. It's not clear to me how you'd extend the definition to a collection of points in R^2. Or is this an entirely unrelated notion of geometric mean?

Comment: @MarkDickinson, my mistake, meant geometric median, not geometric mean

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: (BTW, I recommend using [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) to shorten those long denominators.)

Comment: Can you give specific example inputs (point sets, gamma, iteration count) that are causing difficulties? With some brief experiments here, your code worked well for me.

Comment: Could be that your gamma value is too high; have you tried using an [*adaptive* value method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Description)?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Here is an example of some inputs I just tested that were giving incorrect results: `p = [(1,0), (-math.sqrt(3)/2, 1/2), (-math.sqrt(3)/2, -1/2)]`

Those are all points on the unit circle, so the minima should be the center, however for this call

`gm = geoMean(p, .000001, 5000000)`

I get the answer that the minima is `(-0.5773490199423273, 0.0)`

Comment: @wjmccann: Thanks. For those inputs, it looks as though your code is giving the right answer. The sum of the distances from the origin will be 3. The sum of the distances to the point `(-1/sqrt(3), 0)` that your code found is `1 + sqrt(3)`, which is smaller.

Comment: BTW, did you mean to use `(-1/2, sqrt(3)/2)` and `(-1/2, -sqrt(3)/2)` for your second and third points? In that case, I'd agree that symmetry implies that the geometric median must be at the origin.